# Do unused unreal starter content affect fps?

Tags: frame-rate, unreal-engine4

I am getting a really terrible fps on epic or high quality. I have a 512mb GPU.I just want a low fps around 30-40.My scene only contains a room having some textures. Do I am expecting more or is there any way to solve this problem.I thought may be its because of starter content which i hadn't used.

Answer (score 0):

**I think your computer is the problem here**

Recommended Hardware

**Windows 7 64-bit or Mac OS X 10.9.2 or later**

**Quad-core Intel or AMD processor, 2.5 GHz or faster**

**NVIDIA GeForce 470 GTX or AMD Radeon 6870 HD series card or higher**

**8 GB RAM**

Here, I provide a link to thier page https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Recommended_Hardware